# C++: creating shortcut in Windows - real working example using MinGW/g++

Tags: c++

After some researches I found the solution how to create shortcut in Windows using C++/MinGW/g++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HRESULT CreateLink(
        LPCWSTR FilePath,
        LPCWSTR LnkPath,
        LPCWSTR LnkDesc,
        LPCWSTR WorkDir) {


    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IShellLinkW* psl;

    HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_ShellLink,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IShellLink,
            (LPVOID *) & psl);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
        IPersistFile* ppf;

        wstring file(L"C:\\jarlauncher.exe");
        psl->SetPath((LPWSTR)file.c_str());//Not working - only first letter is visible in created shortcut properties

        psl->SetWorkingDirectory(WorkDir);
        psl->SetDescription(LnkDesc);

        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*) & ppf);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
            hres = ppf->Save(LnkPath, TRUE);
            ppf->Release();
        }

        psl->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return hres;
}
```

Still testing. The problem is that `psl->SetDescription(LnkDesc);` - only one symbol is visible in created shortcut. The same with other fields. What could be the problem here?

But I can create shortcut with Unicode name (added some Japanese characters):

```
...
   hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*) &ppf);

        wstring shortCutName(L"C:\\猫が好き?.lnk");

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
            hres = ppf->Save((LPWSTR)shortCutName.c_str(), TRUE);
            ppf->Release();
        }
...
```

**EDIT:**

Now working example:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

HRESULT CreateLink(
        LPCWSTR filePath,
        LPCWSTR workDir,
        LPCWSTR desc,
        LPCWSTR iconPath,
        LPCWSTR linkPath) {

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IShellLinkW* psl;

    HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_ShellLink,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IShellLinkW,
            (LPVOID*) &psl);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {

        IPersistFile* ppf;

        psl->SetPath(filePath);
        psl->SetWorkingDirectory(workDir);
        psl->SetDescription(desc);
        psl->SetIconLocation(iconPath, 0);

        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*) &ppf);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
            hres = ppf->Save(linkPath, TRUE);
            ppf->Release();
        }

        psl->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return hres;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    CreateLink(
            L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl\\Appl.exe",
            L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl",
            L"Location: C:\\Program Files\\Appl",
            L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl\\someIcon.ico",
            L"C:\\Appl.lnk");//Shortcut will be created at C:/

    return 0;
}
```

You also need to add `Ole32.lib` and `Uuid.lib` library files in project properties. If you don't need terminal window - just add `-mwindows` to C++ compiler option.  That's all - no more "secret" information.

This file is tested on Windows + NetBeans IDE 8.0 with C/C++ plugin, plus MinGW and msys installed at C:\ and properly configured in NetBeans IDE current project properties.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem, perhaps with an example? For starters, you forgot to include `<iostream>`.

Comment: Shortcut is created, but when I open it's properties - only one letter of Start in, Commentare visible, though for example `SetDescription(...)` was long text.

Comment: I think it's something with unicode - `IShellLinkW*` declared as Unicode, but looks like it is expecting ANSI strings. If I change it to `IShellLink*` - everything works fine... But I need Unicode support.

Comment: Just to verify, is sizeof(wchar_t) 2 in MinGW?  It's implementation-defined; GCC on Linux uses 4, while the Windows API expects 2.

Comment: Yes, it's 2, I've tried it.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis, Is `UNICODE` defined? You can't cast between wide and narrow strings and expect it to work, and if the functions take a `LPCTSTR` and you say they expect a narrow string, then you'll have to take note of that. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to specify a wide version of each member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't explicitly have `UNICODE` defined, if you had then it should have invoked the conditional code:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define IID_IShellLink IID_IShellLinkW
#else
#define IID_IShellLink IID_IShellLinkA
#endif
```

Which gives you the wide version of the `IShellLink` interface when you ask for the generic version of IShellLink. In your case, you'll have to explicitly replace the `IID_IShellLink` with `IID_IShellLinkW` and it will instantiate the wide version when you call `CoCreateInstance`, and thus you get all the wide routines.

> The headers look somewhat different between the official MS SDK and the mingw conversion (I think it's accomplished using the `__MINGW_NAME_AW()` macro in those headers.

Comment: @Petesh - Thank you so much. Now it works perfectly. I have changed `IID_IShellLink` to `IID_IShellLinkW`.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis: Actually the code doesn't compile anyway, due to e.g. missing right parenthesis before comment "Not working".

Comment: +1 I posted a comment that the code shouldn't compile if above was the problem, but that was wrong. So learned something new today, that this kind of error is possible. Thanks @Petesh.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf - edited, now it should be OK. It is just an example - it even do not uses constructor arguments.. BUT - it is a REAL WORKING example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the necro, but I wanted to add a note to this...
I've been trying to find refs on how to read .lnk files, using MinGW 32-bit, on Windows 10 Pro, using iShellLink

This solution is perfect - almost... It *does* compile and run, but does not create the link file... It turns out that the problem was the destination location: non-Admin programs don't have authority to write to C:\

I will enclose my working program... note that in addition to including paths/files in the initial call to CreateLink(), I also revised the include files to be valid for MinGW 32-bit.

```
// build:  g++ create_link.cpp -o create_link.exe -lole32 -luuid
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

HRESULT CreateLink(
        LPCWSTR filePath,
        LPCWSTR workDir,
        LPCWSTR desc,
        LPCWSTR iconPath,
        LPCWSTR linkPath) 
{

   CoInitialize(NULL);
   IShellLinkW* psl;

   HRESULT hres = CoCreateInstance(
           CLSID_ShellLink,
           NULL,
           CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
           IID_IShellLinkW,
           (LPVOID*) &psl);

   if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {

       IPersistFile* ppf;

       psl->SetPath(filePath);
       psl->SetWorkingDirectory(workDir);
       psl->SetDescription(desc);
       psl->SetIconLocation(iconPath, 0);

       hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*) &ppf);

       if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
           hres = ppf->Save(linkPath, TRUE);
           ppf->Release();
       }

       psl->Release();
   }
   else {
      printf("CoCreateInstance failed\n");
   }

   CoUninitialize();
   return hres;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    CreateLink(
            // L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl\\Appl.exe",
            // L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl",
            L"D:\\apps\\showin.exe",
            L"D:\\apps",
            L"Location: D:\\apps",
            // L"C:\\Program Files\\Appl\\someIcon.ico",
            L"D:\\icons\\radiation.ico",
            L"C:\\home\\showin.lnk");

    return 0;
}
```